# Database schema version (2.5.11) does not match CMS version (3.1.1).

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.1

**I have been upgrading a joomla (2.5- to - 3.1)** site locally but the upgrade is broken. The sql upgrade did not pass. I have been trying to use the database fix option but even like that did not get it to work in my case.

```
Database schema version (2.5.11) does not match CMS version (3.1.1).

Table '#__content' does not have column 'title_alias' with type 'VARCHAR(255)'. (From file 1.7.3-2011-10-15.sql.)
```

I have been trying to execute manually the other query but fails.

How could I fix my broken tables?

Where could I get a valid sql upgrade script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clicking the "Fix" button on the Extension Manager > Database view.  If this still does not resolve your issue, you'll need to manually apply all of the fixes.  You can grab the SQL updates from [GitHub](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/3.1.1/administrator/components/com_admin/sql/updates/mysql) (the same relative file path applies as well) and manually run each file's queries using a tool such as phpMyAdmin.  Note you'll need to change the table prefix (#__) to match that of your own site.

Comment: thanks for your feedback! I have been trying to get the proper sql script from github but without any success. However installing joomla package as extension fixed couple of problems,

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem when doing upgrade 2.5.11 => 3.1.1, fixed it by first using phpmyadmin to *add* a title_alias field with VARCHAR(50) to #__contents table.
after which joomla added another complaint that title_alias should not exist in 3.0.

After applying 'Fix' I guess the old update scripts for 1.7 first changed title_alias to VARCHAR(255), then the update for 3.0 removed it again, updated the schema version in the db
and joomla stopped complaining...
Hope this helps you.